# Adding metadata specific to each post in Jekyll

Tags: html, metadata, jekyll, liquid, head

I've built a blog and would like to add specific meta data to each post in the blog.

At the start of each page I have the following code (simplified to make clear the question I'm asking).

```
---
layout: default
title:  "Title"
date:   2018-04-19
---
```

Which goes off and pull in my default.html in _layout

deafault.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  {% include head.html %}
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

head.html is where I have the head portion of my website. In there, there is some general header data that I would like on every page. 
What I'm trying to ask is what is a good way to add page/post specific meta data to each post using Jekyll and liquid (in addition to the general meta data I have already for the overall site)? Where in the flow should I add this page/post specific metadata?

Thanks!

Comment: [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) works anywhere inside [`<head>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu. Thanks for the comment, I understand that. I'll try to be more clear. I have meta data that applies to the site. But then for each post I create I want to make additional meta data, to help search engines see that the post is about a specific topic.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Understood. I'm not asking how search engines handle this / or work... Instead I'm asking how to use Jekyll / Liquid to pull in post specific meta data per post. Which seems like a valid coding question to  me. And thank you for the link, looking through it.

Comment: This is available out of the box with jekyll : [jekyll seo](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag)

Answer (score 4):

So did some more web searching and was able to find the following. (So all credit to this site for the following code snippets.) Which is the direct answer to my original question, but Andrei did provide a good point (see further below).

https://ehelion.com/blog/2018/02/24/adding-meta-keywords-jekyll.html

Add this to the head.html:

```
{% if page.keywords %}
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ page.keywords | join: ', ' | escape }}">
{% endif %}
```

Add this to YAML font matter:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Best blog post ever made"
date:   2029-01-01 16:20:00
keywords:
  - some keyword
  - another keyword
  - get rich quick
---
```

Also thanks to Andrei Gheorghiu for providing that link because it explains that search engines don't really care about the keywords tag anymore. Instead the focus has shifted to meta descriptions. But the same type of code can be applied. Just swap out if page.keywords to if page.description and put a description in the YAML font matter.

Comment: This works but the example is misleading, as the keywords metatag is probably one that is least important. E.g. by Google it is ignored for almost a decade: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag